# Python Tkinter type check

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I want to check an entry boxes input:
`ProductNameEntry.get()` to check whether any of the inputted data contains any integers if so it should return an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry box data is a `str`.
To check if there are numbers in the string you can use `any([char.isdigit() for char in your_string])` which returns `True` when there's a number in the `your_string`